# Problem with deploy AWS Lambda as Docker image

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, nestjs

I'm using NestJS monorepo to hold multiple AWS Lambda Functions. Below is my project structure:

```
- root
-- apps
--- lambda-one
---- src
----- main.ts //  <- lambda handler
-- node_modules
-- package.json
-- template.yaml
-- Dockerfile
```

I'm using also AWS Sam Template to create architecture as a code. Below is my configuration:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Resources:
  LambdaOne:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: .
      DockerTag: v1
      DockerBuildArgs:
        NODE_ENV: dev
```

I want to deploy this Lambda as a docker image, so I create a multi-staged Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:16 as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY /apps/lambda-one ./apps/lambda-one
COPY package.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY tsconfig.build.json ./
COPY nest-cli.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN npm install --global yarn

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build lambda-one

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

CMD ["dist/apps/lambda-one/main.handler"]
```

Can someone tell me why, when I try to invoke this function, I've got this error?

```
ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'main'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'main'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/index.mjs","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)","    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)","    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"]}
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 562.92 ms
```

Comment: are you exporting the handler fun from your app?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following things.

1. The lambda function has exported the handler function
2. The dist folder contains the correct file with proper name that you are calling.
3. Try running your docker locally and test all the things / paths before running it to lambda.

   docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh your-image-name